# Is there a way to put code blocks in block quotes?

Tags: support, markdown

I posted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641678/1547004) using text from this [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations) page.

I tried using block quotes for the text, but if I indent the code, it breaks the block quote, and if I don't indent it, it doesn't display as code.

Comment: Apply the code blocks first, then select everything at once and apply the block quote format.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The blockquote Markdown syntax allows for an optional space after `>`, so in order to have code formatted inside a blockquote, you will need a `>` followed by **five** spaces instead of the usual four, to give the code formatting the four spaces it needs and let the blockquote formatting eat up its optional space.

To illustrate:

```
> Some code:
>
>       // code goes here
```

renders as

> Some code:
>
> ```
>   // code goes here
> ```

Answer (score 41):

Apparently this also works:

````
> Some code:
>
> ```lang-js
> const a = 0
> ```
````

Demo:

> Some code:
>
> ```js
> const a = 0
> ```

Useful because the accepted answer doesn't work on Github or on my Jekyll blog.

Comment: Also works in GitHub-flavored Markdown.

Comment: It fails if there two or more carriage return between the code lines. Any solution for that?

Comment: @AmitJoshi see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another option: Since Markdown is a superset of HTML, you can use the `<blockquote>` element to wrap the code block (note the blank lines after the opening & before the closing tag):

````
<blockquote>

```lua
print"Hello World!"
```

</blockquote>
````

is rendered as:

> ```lua
> print"Hello World!"
> ```

The advantages of this approach are that (1) it's supposed to work everywhere where CommonMark is supported (which goes beyond SO) and (2) you don't need to prefix every line of code with `>` .

Answer (score 6):

### Syntax highlighting

You can also add syntax highlighting when you use blockquotes:

Code:

```
> Some code:
>
> <!-- language: lang-js -->
> 
>     const a = 0
```

Demo:

> Some code:
>
> ```js
> const a = 0
> ```

Comment: That's... alarming. A syntax highlighter should **never** rewrite anyone's code, regardless of the implications of the original code. A syntax highlighter is not, and should not act as, a linter (and even then a linter *tells* you what you could do better without *rewriting* your code).

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not sure if you are joking because we were. I just made a typo.

Comment: Oh, OK. Yeah I was uh... prepared to write a post about it.